# Generate executable a.out from cpp mentioned in .pro file in yocto build

Tags: c++, c++11, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am using yocto build. I have **.pro** files and recipes(**.bb**) which build all cpp files present in **.pro** file. Recently I added two new cpp file i.e. **gtest_main.cpp** and **lgeplugin_Test.cpp** in **.pro** file. As show below

**lgeplugin.pro**

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -g
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -g
CFLAGS += \
           -Wall \
          -Wextra \
          -fPIC \
          -std=c++11



TARGET = lgeplugin
TEMPLATE = lib

message(Building)

INCLUDEPATH += ${Root}/include/ALL \
               ${Root}/include/gtest \

 DEFINES += USE_LGE_TREE
 SOURCES += ../../src/lgeplugin.cpp

 contains(DEFINES, LGE_PLUGIN) {
   
SOURCES     += \
                ../../src/internalclient.cpp \
                ../../src/Event.cpp \
                ../../src/gtest_main.cpp \
                ../../src/lgeplugin_Test.cpp
LIBS += -lLGEFramework -lgtest
    }
```

**lgeplugin.bb**

```
QMAKE_PROFILES = "${S}/lgeplugin.pro"
do_install() {
        install -d ${D}/usr/lib
        cp -a ${B}/liblgeplugin.so* ${D}/usr/lib
}
```

**Requirement : I need  executable(a.out) of the newly added file i.e. gtest_main.cpp and lgeplugin_Test.cpp**

Comment: I'm fairly new to yocto; but we use it to build embedded Qt projects at my workplace. We use the meta-qt5 layer from openembedded: https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5. There's a `qmake5.bbclass` which you can inherit, and it will configure the build environment so that `qmake` can find Qt5, and then use it to build and install the target. Note, this has dependencies on Qt5, so using this layer will build Qt5 as part of your distro and it's a pretty hefty chunk of code to be compiling.